# 2D android game Development tool in Linux OS

Tags: android, linux, mobile, game-engine

I plan to start making a simple 2D android mobile game,
I'm using Linux Ubuntu operating system...
want to ask how should I start and what software and game engine can i use in Linux OS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use unity game engine it has support for android and is easy to start and learn https://unity3d.com it has very good support and is popular game engine and you can use it with linux OS. Unity works on linux ubuntu on WINE quit well.

Comment: Is any tool can use without wine?

Comment: Unreal Engine 4 can be run without wine.